# How to set hover to an element that contains an icon

Tags: html, css

The `a` tag that contains a search icon in my navbar doesn't show hover styles properly. when I hover over it, it only changes the background color of the icon, not the `a` tag. the solutions to the other questions can't solve my problem.

```
<a href="#" class="absolute search hover:text-white">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      fill="currentColor"
      class="w-5 h-5"
    >
      <rect class="w-full h-full" fill="white" fill-opacity="0" />
      <path
        fill-rule="evenodd"
        d="M10.5 3.75a6.75 6.75 0 100 13.5 6.75 6.75 0 000-13.5zM2.25 10.5a8.25 8.25 0 1114.59 5.28l4.69 4.69a.75.75 0 11-1.06 1.06l-4.69-4.69A8.25 8.25 0 012.25 10.5z"
        clip-rule="evenodd"
      />
    </svg>
  </a>


.search {
  left: 96%;
}
.search:hover rect {
  fill: #f44336;
  fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

demo: https://fudev2009.github.io/name/

Comment: You should provide your code here. Your link can be invisible at some point so it's not trustable.

Comment: @NickVu i've added that tag and its styles in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `rect` to fill `svg` with a background color

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" fill-opacity="0"/>
```

And then use `.search:hover rect` to modify `rect` styles on hovering

```
.search:hover rect {
   fill: #f44336;
   fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

```css
.search {
  left: 96%;
}

.search:hover {
  color: white;
}

.search:hover rect {
  fill: #f44336;
  fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="absolute search">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5">
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" fill-opacity="0"/>
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M10.5 3.75a6.75 6.75 0 100 13.5 6.75 6.75 0 000-13.5zM2.25 10.5a8.25 8.25 0 1114.59 5.28l4.69 4.69a.75.75 0 11-1.06 1.06l-4.69-4.69A8.25 8.25 0 012.25 10.5z"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
          />
  </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: I modified my code the same way as you did but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @NguyễnLânDũng, could you share your modification and your website in your question?

Comment: why did I put the edit the wrong place??? anyway, that's it

Comment: `class="w-full h-full"` You modified the width and heigh of `rect` which is unexpected. You should keep the attribute width and height like this `width="100%" height="100%"` @NguyễnLânDũng

Comment: I tried removing those classes in the dev tools but when I do that, the background color is not #f44336 but a gray color and it still only applies to the icon, not to the mother element

Comment: Did you add these width and height attributes `width="100%" height="100%"` on `rect`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247794/discussion-between-nguyn-lan-dng-and-nick-vu).